# Centring logo in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

How do I center the logo at the top of a form? I've looked at the formatting options, but it seems to only allow uploading the logo, not centring or repositioning within the page.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue as well, and I solved it by playing around with the borders of the logo until it was centred.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

Although we do not offer the ability to center the logo at this time. We are looking to do this in the future. You can follow our progress over on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/YBnu0cLi). You can center the logo if you are embedding the form on your website with CSS. I understand if you don't to share your website in a forum. If you would like to submit a [help request](http://help.cognitoforms.com/request-help), we can take a look at your site and help create the CSS to center your logo. Once a working CSS solution has been found I can add the code here to help other user with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note that as of last week Cognito Forms supports centering a logo on a form (as well as a number of other style enhancements).   (I am a support engineer for Cognito Forms.)